# Place/City names from a list of CLLocation

Tags: ios, swift, cllocation, reverse-geocoding

Here is my situation. (Using Swift 2.2)

I have a list of coordinates (`CLLocation`). I need to call the `reverseGeocodeLocation` to fetch the corresponding Place/City. If I try to loop through the elements there is a chance for some calls to fails as Apple suggest to send one call in a second. So I need to add a delay between each calls as well.

Is there any way to achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

(If we have multiple items with same lat, long we only call the api once)

Comment: Partially related - where does the list of coordinates come from? make sure you cache the results to avoid making network calls for results you've obtained in the past.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, If we have multiple items with same lat, long we only call the api once.

The list is from the Photo library. (We save the details in DB and uses these items)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code declares a set of locations and looks them up one by one, with at least 1 second between requests:

```
    var locations = Set<CLLocation>()

    func reverseGeocodeLocation() {
        guard let location = locations.popFirst() else {
            geocodingDone()
            return
        }
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
            //Do stuff here
            //Dispatch the next request in 1 second
            _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { _ in
                self.reverseGeocodeLocation()
            }
        }
    }

    func geocodingDone() {
        //Put your finish logic in here
    }
```

FYI I used the block syntax for the Timer, but that only works on iOS 10.  If you are using iOS 9 or earlier just use the selector version and it works the same way.